# How to see where links to 404 pages are found in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, links, 404, referrer

I've found the Google Search Console report where it lists all the 404 Not Found Errors on the site. But when I click into each URL, it doesn't tell me WHERE on the website these links are actually located.

How do I find out where these links are located on the site?

Comment: Have you clicked to "inspect URL" to see the "Referring page"?   It isn't always there, but it usually is.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller says "None detected"...confused as to why it's in the report then...is there some other way to find out the referring page(s) ?

Comment: You don't have to fix every single 404 error on your site.  Google expects unexpected URLs to give a 404 status.  If Google doesn't report a referrer, there may not be anything left to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a reliable way to identify these pages within Google.

However, [Siteliner.com](http://www.siteliner.com) has worked well for me to find these.  After having Siteliner scan your site, there's a section for broken links and it will show you both the problem URL and the link it's buried in.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about Siteliner. Incredible to me that there's no way to discover this info in Search Console! Wow